# Rails, How i can create grouped_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new in rails and i need a help.
I wanna to do a grouped selection on rails but i dont know how i can do it.

i have 3 db tables cars, car_brands and car_models. When i add new car i need to select car model, how i can do it with gtouped selection.

> models/car_brand.rb

```
class CarBrand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  has_many :car_models

  mount_uploader :logo, CarBrandImgUploader
end
```

> models/car_model.rb

```
class CarModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars
  belongs_to :car_brand

end
```

> cars_controller.rb

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_car, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_model, only: [:index, :new, :edit]    

  # GET /cars
  # GET /cars.json
  def index
    @cars = Car.all

  end

  # GET /cars/1
  # GET /cars/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /cars/new
  def new
    @car = Car.new
  end

  # GET /cars/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /cars
  # POST /cars.json
  def create
    @car = Car.new(car_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.save
        if params[:ImagesCars]
          params[:ImagesCars]['image'].each do |a|
            @ImagesCar = @car.ImagesCars.create!(:image => a, :car_id => @car.id)
          end
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cars/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cars/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @car.update(car_params)
        if params[:ImagesCars]
          params[:ImagesCars]['image'].each do |a|
            @ImagesCar = @car.ImagesCars.create!(:image => a, :car_id => @car.id)
          end
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @car }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cars/1
  # DELETE /cars/1.json
  def destroy
    @car.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cars_url, notice: 'Car was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_car
      @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_model
      @models = CarModel.all
      @brands = CarBrand.all
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def car_params
      params.require(:car).permit(:title_en, :keys_en, :description_en, :text_en, :title_fr, :keys_fr, :description_fr, :text_fr, :title_ru, :keys_ru, :description_ru, :text_ru, :title_es, :keys_es, :description_es, :text_es, :model_id, :brand_id, :price_day, :price_week, :p_info, :images_cars => [:id, :car_id, :image])
    end
end
```

> cars/new.html.haml

```
= simple_form_for(@car, html: { role: 'form', multipart: true }) do |f|
 = f.input :price_day, as: :integer, input_html: {class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Price Day ej: 150'}
 = f.cktext_area :text_en, as: :text, input_html: { class: 'form-control' },  :label => 'EN Website Content Text EN'
 =f.input :model_id, collection: @models, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :brand_id
= f.submit 'Save'
```

i get this error:
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Please help or explain how i can do the grouped selection. 
Thx

Comment: You should post the stack trace in order to see the line and the file of the error

Comment: My guess is that `@models` isn't instantiated yet. I don't see where `set_model` is called. Perhaps you meant to add `before_filter :set_model`?

Comment: `=f.input :model_id, collection: @models, as: :grouped_select, group_method: :model`
I modificate this line and get this error:
'undefined method `map' for "SL viano 350":String'